# How to calculate Moving Average with time series data at 24, 48, and 72 hours?

Tags: r, moving-average

I am trying to calculate the moving average for each `name` in the dataset below at 1, 2 , and 3 days. Here is the example of what my dataset looks like (the dput example was a little long for this question):

```
 Date_Time_GMT_3         name                      value
  <dttm>                 <chr>                     <dbl>
1 2021-07-08 07:15:00  20817729_2PT_Stationary    21.5
2 2021-07-08 07:15:00  20822229_4PT_Stationary    17.9
3 2021-07-08 07:15:00  20819744_6PT_AIR           17.9
4 2021-07-08 08:30:00  20817729_2PT_Stationary    18.6
5 2021-07-08 08:30:00  20822229_4PT_Stationary    16.5
6 2021-07-08 08:30:00  20819744_6PT_AIR           19.0
7 2021-07-09 10:45:00  20817729_2PT_Stationary    21.5
8 2021-07-09 10:45:00  20822229_4PT_Stationary    17.9
9 2021-07-09 10:45:00  20819744_6PT_AIR           17.9
10 2021-07-11 09:15:00  20817729_2PT_Stationary    18.6
11 2021-07-11 09:15:00  20822229_4PT_Stationary    16.5
12 2021-07-11 09:15:00  20819744_6PT_AIR           19.0
13 2021-07-12 15:45:00  20817729_2PT_Stationary    21.5
14 2021-07-12 15:45:00  20822229_4PT_Stationary    17.9
15 2021-07-12 15:45:00  20819744_6PT_AIR           17.9
16 2021-07-13 06:15:00  20817729_2PT_Stationary    18.6
17 2021-07-13 06:15:00  20822229_4PT_Stationary    16.5
18 2021-07-13 06:15:00  20819744_6PT_AIR           19.0
```

I have tried using this code

```
some_data = df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(name) %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(mean_01da = zoo::rollmean(value, k = 1, fill = NA),
                mean_02da = zoo::rollmean(value, k = 2, fill = NA),
                mean_03da = zoo::rollmean(value, k = 3, fill = NA)) %>% 
  dplyr::ungroup()
```

but the moving average isn't over the time specified - I'm thinking because `k` should be the number of rows I want to use for values. Is there a way to calculate the moving average by specifying the number of days to calculate over (i.e. 1, 2, and 3 days) using the date/time column?

Comment: Please provide **reproducible** data.

Comment: By day you mean calendar day? Or the previous 24 hrs/86400 seconds window behind the timestamp?

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez I mean the previous 24 hours behind the timestamp

Comment: And you want a rolling average for every row? In other words, do you want to have the rolling average for every "name" observation, or just the rolling average for the latest name observation?

Comment: @NicolásVelásquez I would prefer a rolling average for the latest name observation

Comment: What I want the final dataframe to have are moving average values for every 24, 48, and 72 hours. And not values for every timestamp. What I want the final dataframe to have are moving average values for every 24, 48, and 72 hours. And not values for every timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Use an expression involving findInterval to find how many rows back to use and note that in rollapplyr we can specify a vector for the number of rows to use.  POSIXct objects use seconds internally so 24 * 3600 is the number of seconds in 24 hours, etc.

```
library(dplyr, exclude = c("lag", "filter"))
library(zoo)

DF %>%
  group_by(name) %>%
  mutate(tt = Date_Time_GMT_3,
    day1 = rollapplyr(value, 1:n() - findInterval(tt - 24 * 3600, tt), mean),
    day2 = rollapplyr(value, 1:n() - findInterval(tt - 48 * 3600, tt), mean),
    day3 = rollapplyr(value, 1:n() - findInterval(tt - 72 * 3600, tt), mean)) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-tt)
```

### Note

The input in reproducible form:

```
DF <-
structure(list(Date_Time_GMT_3 = structure(c(1625742900, 1625742900, 
1625742900, 1625747400, 1625747400, 1625747400, 1625841900, 1625841900, 
1625841900, 1626009300, 1626009300, 1626009300, 1626119100, 1626119100, 
1626119100, 1626171300, 1626171300, 1626171300), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), name = c("20817729_2PT_Stationary", "20822229_4PT_Stationary", 
"20819744_6PT_AIR", "20817729_2PT_Stationary", "20822229_4PT_Stationary", 
"20819744_6PT_AIR", "20817729_2PT_Stationary", "20822229_4PT_Stationary", 
"20819744_6PT_AIR", "20817729_2PT_Stationary", "20822229_4PT_Stationary", 
"20819744_6PT_AIR", "20817729_2PT_Stationary", "20822229_4PT_Stationary", 
"20819744_6PT_AIR", "20817729_2PT_Stationary", "20822229_4PT_Stationary", 
"20819744_6PT_AIR"), value = c(21.5, 17.9, 17.9, 18.6, 16.5, 
19, 21.5, 17.9, 17.9, 18.6, 16.5, 19, 21.5, 17.9, 17.9, 18.6, 
16.5, 19)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "13", "14", "15", 
"16", "17", "18"))
```

Comment: This code works for me, but when I compare it to results in excel they are off. Why would the values not be the same when I'm using the ```Moving Average``` function in excel and  comparing it to the results of this code?

Comment: Well I want to average over ```Num_Hours``` (i.e. 24, 48, and 72 hours). And the dates represent ```yyyy-mm-dd```. The data I have in excel is the exact format I have in R. Is there a way to alter the code so that is fits the same assumptions as the excel function ```Moving Average```?

Comment: Sorry. I mixed up questions.  My comment was intended for a different question and I have now deleted it.  Suggest you show the expected result.  When I calculate the 24 hour value for 2021-07-08 08:30:00 20817729_2PT_Stationary  I get (21.5 + 18.6)/2
 = 20.05 which is the same that the answer using R gives so based on that one  point the answer is correct.

Comment: I think the issue is my question, I am going to try and re-ask this because I can't seem to figure out the issue